# How to display a record set grouped by month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm interested in display a record set of timeline type events in the format:

```
2011
APR
 - Record Out
 - Record Out    
AUG 
 - Record Out
 - Record Out
SEP
 - Record Out
 - Record Out
OCT
 - Record Out
 - Record Out
2009
OCT
 - Record Out
 - Record Out
```

The trick here being it only display the year if there are items in that year to show.. Same for a month, the month grouping only renders if there are records for that month to display. Does rails have any built in grouping for this type of output? Or would this be 100% custom to implement? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Do you want to process the data at the SQL or at the Ruby layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grouping can be done by Ruby's built-in [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) method:

```
events.group_by(&:year).each do |year, year_events|
  puts year, year_events
end
```

I assume you have `event.year` method. The same thing with grouping by months.